# How to include multiple response variables in a bar plot both in the x and the fill variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to build a bar plot similar to the picture below where both the variable displayed on the X axis and the fill variable are multiple response variables, i.e. each row/respondent can select all or one of the options.

[An example of what I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aM4F.png)

A snippet of my dataset where I would like to have the HNV variables in the x axis and filled in by the Provisioning_IN and Regulating_IN ones. All of them are dummy variables and I woudl like to get just the "1" values that indicate the "presence/positive value" of the variable:

```
structure(list(HNV_grasslands = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HNV_arable = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), HNV_permanent_crop = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), HNV_mosaic = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L), Provisioning_IN = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Regulating_IN = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = 10:20, class = "data.frame")
```

So far I managed to create a bar plot with the HNV ones using this code and following examples from other posts in stack overflow:

```
hnvf2 <-hnvf %>%
  select(HNV_grasslands, HNV_arable, HNV_permanent_crop, HNV_mosaic)

hnvf2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols= everything(), 
               names_to = "HNV",
               values_to = "Value") %>%
  filter(Value == "1") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= HNV)) +
  geom_bar( ,fill="turquoise")
```

[What I was able to do so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELb1t.png)

Now I would like to "populate" each of these bars with the count of Provisioning_IN and Regulating_IN, but all the coding I am trying is not working. I am quite new to R and your help would be very appreciated!

Thank you stefan for your help! I am now trying to produce the same graph but with proportions and total numbers of each bar on top, like on this example:[image: Example of what I would like to get]

I can produce the proportions graph, but something goes wrong when I try to include the geom_text command. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is my (wrong) code:

```
hnvf2 |>
    ggplot(aes(x = HNV)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = IN),position ="fill") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1), 
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+
    theme(axis.line.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = "black"),
          axis.ticks.length.y.left = unit(.25, "cm"))+
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA))+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c('arable land', 'grasslands', 'mosaic landscape', 
                              'permanent croplands')) +
geom_text(stat="count", aes(label=after_stat(count)),vjust= 0.5)+
  labs(x= "HNV farmland type", y="Proportion of studies", fill= "")+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(r= 15)))+
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a second `pivot_longer` to tidy your dataset:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

hnvf2 <- hnvf %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("HNV"),
    names_to = c("HNV"),
    names_prefix = "HNV_",
    values_to = "value1"
  ) |>
  pivot_longer(
    cols = ends_with("_IN"),
    names_to = c("IN"),
    values_to = "value2",
    names_pattern = "^(.*)_IN"
  ) |>
  filter(value1 == 1, value2 == 1) |>
  select(-value1, -value2) 

hnvf2 |>
  ggplot(aes(x = HNV)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = IN))
```

[image]